# How can i get an annotation to show up on my map in xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to get an annotation of something but it gives errors I don't know how to get rid of, does anyone happen to know how to solve this?

This is the code I currently have but it says that value of type 'MKPointAnnotation' has no member 'setCoordinate'. And it says: use of unresolved identifier 'map'.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        var WCAula = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.3044, 4.5724)
        // These are the lattitude and longitude of the toilet across the wooden stairs in the auditorium.

        var point1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        point1.setCoordinate(WCAula)
        point1.title = "WCAula"

        map.addAnnotation(point1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The map view you have defined starts with a capital M, whereas the map you refer to begins with a lowercase m. Change it so they are both lowercase as that is the convention in Swift.

As far as setting the coordinate, calling setCoordinate() is Objective-C syntax. In Swift you just set the coordinate directly.

```
point1.coordinate = WCAula
```